# Open new tab in ember controller function

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember controller with a function in it.
In this function I wan to open a new tab.
Here my code:

```
 App.ActivityController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
   actions: {
    downloadOfflineOrderSpreadsheet: function() { this.downloadOfflineOrderSpreadsheets(); },
    }

   downloadOfflineOrderSpreadsheets: function() {
     //here go to a new tab please??
   }
 }
```

This is my very first encounter with ember so don't know much yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you can't directly control if the new window will open in a new tab or a new window, because it's an option controlled by the settings of the users browser.

But as a rule of thumb opening pages using `window.open` that was not initiated by a user event will open the page in a new browser window, much like a popup.

That said, you could do it like this:

```
 App.ActivityController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
   actions: {
     downloadOfflineOrderSpreadsheet: function() {
       this.downloadOfflineOrderSpreadsheets();
     },
     downloadOfflineOrderSpreadsheets: function() {
       //here go to a new tab please??
       window.open('mypage.html');
     }
   }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please note that in mobile web apps (sometimes referred to as "homescreen apps") this may lead to a page you cannot leave, as there is no back button in a web app. I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23135344/3890673) approach instead